# No databases in > mysql

Tags: 14.04, server, mysql

After I upgraded my ubuntu from 14.4 to 16.4 on Digital Ocean, my databases doesn't show when I run the command show databases; It only shows the following: information_schema test

If i go to /var/lib/mysql, my databases files are there.

I'm not sure does it have something with /etc/mysql/my.cnf file and do i need to add info to it, currently it looks like this:

```
#
# The MySQL database server configuration file.
#
# You can copy this to one of:
# - "/etc/mysql/my.cnf" to set global options,
# - "~/.my.cnf" to set user-specific options.
# 
# One can use all long options that the program supports.
# Run program with --help to get a list of available options and with
# --print-defaults to see which it would actually understand and use.
#
# For explanations see
# http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/server-system-variables.html

#
# * IMPORTANT: Additional settings that can override those from this file!
#   The files must end with '.cnf', otherwise they'll be ignored.
#

!includedir /etc/mysql/conf.d/
!includedir /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/
```

if i run next comands i got this output

```
mysql> SHOW DATABASES;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER();
+----------------+----------------+
| USER()         | CURRENT_USER() |
+----------------+----------------+
| root@localhost | root@localhost |
+----------------+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SHOW GRANTS;
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@localhost                                    |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost'                     |
| GRANT PROXY ON ''@'' TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+--------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Most simple fix would be to restore a backup of your database.

Comment: To upload .sql dump files using workbench / terminal? If so, i got this error when i try to create or import : Executing:
CREATE SCHEMA `test` ;

Operation failed: std::exception
ERROR 1044: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'test'
SQL Statement:
CREATE SCHEMA `test`

Comment: What happens if you create a dummy table or db(`test2`)? Does it appear in your db folder?

Comment: if i try to create it i got ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' to database 'test'

Answer (score 0):

Ok so problem was with user root privileges, 
i just Stop the MySQL server and then restart it with the

```
sudo /usr/sbin/mysqld --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &
```

after which i connect to the MySQL server using the **mysql** client

```
shell> mysql
```

then i grant all privileges to root user

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

After that I stop the server and restart it normally,
Now when i call `SHOW DATABASES;` it listed all my databases, and i'm able to create new one.

Thanks to everyone for the help.